# VC++ 6 Linker Errors

Tags: c++, linker, visual-c++-6

Basically, what's happening is this: I have a VC6 workspace (contains 3 projects total), and after NOT being able to succesfully port it into VS2010, I installed XP on a virtual machine (Win 7 on host machine), and installed VS6 on the devbox.

From there, I was able to get past compilation errors, and land headfirst into a whole slew of linker errors...

and I have no idea what's wrong. If anyone could help me with this it would be tremendously appreciated!

(an excert from the build log, there's 41 linker errors total...)

```
>Linking...
MainFrm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall ReportMenuBuilder::~ReportMenuBuilder(void)" (??1ReportMenuBuilder@@UAE@XZ)
MainFrm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ReportMenuBuilder::ReportMenuBuilder(void)" (??0ReportMenuBuilder@@QAE@XZ)
MainFrm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ReportMenuBuilder::Build(bool)" (?Build@ReportMenuBuilder@@QAE_N_N@Z)
MainFrm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CReportMultiDocTemplate::GetDocumentCount(void)const " (?GetDocumentCount@CReportMultiDocTemplate@@QBEHXZ)
MainFrm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class CString __thiscall ReportMenuBuilder::GetFilespecGivenID(unsigned int)const " (?GetFilespecGivenID@ReportMenuBuilder@@QBE?AVCString@@I@Z)
```

Only thing I can think of is apparently the projects are having trouble seeing the necessary files from the other projects, but I don't know why.

Comment: First question - does it build on a real XP box?

Comment: Could that be part of Crystal Reports? Did you install that?

Comment: This is code from years ago, and it is a working product, so I would assume it builds on a real XP box.

Comment: @kogh I don't see why you would assume that.

Comment: The VM is (IMHO) unlikely to be a problem.  More likely it's a missing lib, or perhaps a lib compiled with a different compiler version.  Something that contains the "ReportMenuBuilder" code.  Do you have the old build scripts and environmentmset up correctly?  EnvVars, dependency libs or SDKs, that sort of thing.

Comment: If it was a lib missing doesn't the VC6 complier report that it can't find that lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess would be you haven't added the .lib file to the additional imports of the other projects.  If you have dumpbin the binaries and see if you see the export.